# need to get Posted data as fast as i can

Tags: c#

I created a web page to receive some data Posted from third party
My code is follows

```
    static StreamReader sr;
    string data = string.Empty;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["Name"] != null)
            {
                data = Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString();
                ProcessData(data);
            }
            else if (Page.Request.InputStream.Length > 0)
            {
                sr = new StreamReader(Page.Request.InputStream);
                data = Server.UrlDecode(sr.ReadToEnd());
                sr.Close();
                ProcessData(data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger(ex.ToString() + " StackTrace: " + Convert.ToString(ex.StackTrace));
        }
    }
```

I need to get the posted data and response within 1000 milliseconds.
But it is sometime more than 3 seconds and sometime less than a second.
Please tell what are the chances. And how can i reduce this time taken.
Please someone help...

Comment: If this is over the internet, there's not much you can do about it. Latency can be a major bottleneck. You can start by timing your own code, see how much it takes to process that.

Comment: Do you have to ReadToEnd() immediately?  For a large stream this could take a while.  I am wondering if you could do your processing without reading all the way to the stream end?

Comment: Do not only time your code, have a look at the IIS processing too. 1000 ms is a very short interval for receiving data and sending a response. What will happen when the post contains 200 MB of data?

Comment: the files will be less than 1 kb.

Answer (score 0):

How much data are we talking about? That's going to make a big difference.

Below a certain amount, your approach of reading in a single string is more performant, however, beyond a couple of kilobytes, you're going to generally get better performance from rewriting ProcessData so that it has an overload that takes a `TextReader` and passing `sr` to that - it could either handle the url-unescaping itself or do so with a pass-through reader that you pass `sr` to and which does the url-unescaping as it is read-from.

Just where the threshold is, is hard to say. In deciding which to go for, I'd be balancing data size vs difficulty of taking this approach. With anything that can be easily adapted (anything that does interpreting in a single pass, writes to another stream, stores in a database, passes to an `XmlReader` would be cases where this would be really easy) I'd do it for anything over 2-4kiB or maybe even less (the `XmlReader` example would be so easy that I'd quite possibly do this even for minute data). When things get more difficult, I'd resist it until we're talking about a few hundred kiB or I **really** care about performance.

Can any of the processing be deferred? If so, you can pass that work of to another thread, and send a response quicker.